# lodash sort an array of objects by a property which has an array of objects

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a an object. I am able to sort the items by using lodash's `_.orderBy()`. 
However, in one of the scenario I have to sort by `subject`, which is an array of objects. Items inside the `subject` array are already sorted based on the `name`.

As `subject` is an array of the objects, I need to consider the first item for sorting.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "peter",
    "subject": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "maths"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "social"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "david",
    "subject": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "physics"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "science"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Justin",
    "subject": [
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) to extract the `name` (or `id`) of the 1st item in `subjects`. If no item exists, `_.get()` will return `undefined`, which can be replaced with a default value.  In this case, we don't want to use an empty string as a default value, since the order would change. Instead I'm checking if the value is a string, if it is I use lower case on it, if not I return it as is.

```js
const arr = [{"id":"1","name":"peter","subject":[{"id":"1","name":"maths"},{"id":"2","name":"social"}]},{"id":"2","name":"david","subject":[{"id":"2","name":"physics"},{"id":"3","name":"science"}]},{"id":"3","name":"Justin","subject":[]}]

const result = _.orderBy(arr, o => {
  const name = _.get(o, 'subject[0].name')
  
  return _.isString(name) ? name.toLowerCase() : name
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. It worked great. But I always use .tolowercase() in my orderBy just to make sure it is not case sensitive. So when I apply .tolowercase to above the code, I am getting an error because one of the item doesn't have any subjects. const result = _.orderBy(arr, o => _.get(o, 'subject[0].name').toLowercase())

Comment: See update. Although we can use `_.get()` default value and set an empty string, this will change the sort order. The solution is to check if the `name` is a string, if it does set it to lower case, and if not return it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.sortBy` with a comparison/sorting function argument. Your function itself can look into the receiving arguments `subject` key (I think its the subject you want to compare?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the question also tagged with `ES6` here is an JS only solution via [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
let arr = [ { "id": "1", "name": "peter", "subject": [ { "id": "1", "name": "maths" }, { "id": "2", "name": "social" } ] }, { "id": "2", "name": "david", "subject": [ { "id": "2", "name": "physics" }, { "id": "3", "name": "science" } ] }, { "id": "3", "name": "Justin", "subject": [] }, ] 

const result = arr.sort((a,b) => 
  a.subject.length && b.subject.length 
   ? a.subject[0].name.localeCompare(b.subject[0].name) 
   : a.subject.length ? -1 : 1)

console.log(result)
```